# Does ReDim work to reduce the size of an array VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a list of DNS names that changes frequently.  It used to be okay for me to change a couple scripts by adding lines (and subscript declarations) for an array in the script(s).  this process, however, is getting cumbersome.

I would like to be able to write the DNS names to a file (multiple, if possible) and read them into an array, so i can push files to those DNS names only.

So far, i have this script to test the principle (and it is already not working)

```
'Set Constants
ON Error RESUME NEXT
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2
Const FOR_APPENDING = 8

Sub Pause(strPause)
     WScript.Echo (strPause)
     z = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
End Sub



'Declare the Combine Sub
Sub CombineFile( ByVal readfile)
  Set inputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(readfile, FOR_READING)
  Wscript.Echo readfile
  For Each line in File.ReadAllLines(inputFile)
    Wscript.Echo line & vbCrLf
  Next
  Pause("Press Enter to continue")
End Sub

CombineFile("C:\scripts\IPLIST-P.txt")
```

This code is not producing an error (which is why i added the Pause into the script, thanks 'MacAnanny M')

EDIT:

I have figured out that I needed ReadLine instead of ReadAllLines (see below).   I also removed the "Pause" since it figured out the problem.  Thansk for all involved

```
   'Set Constants
ON Error RESUME NEXT
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2
Const FOR_APPENDING = 8

'Declare the Combine Sub
dim i
dim arrServerList()
i=0
Sub CombineFile( ByVal readfile)
  Set inputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(readfile, FOR_READING)
'  Wscript.Echo readfile
  dim servername
  Do until inputFile.AtEndOfStream
    ReDim Preserve arrServerList(i+1)
    servername = inputFile.ReadLine
'    WScript.Echo servername
'    objTS.write servername & vbCrLf
    arrServerList(i) = servername
    i=i+1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Then i would simply need to call it (any number of times) to add to my array variable (as long as i didn't overwrite the `i` value)

```
CombineFile("C:\scripts\IPLIST-D.txt")
CombineFile("C:\scripts\IPLIST-Q.txt")
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: `This code is not producing an error.`  Wouldn't the `ON Error RESUME NEXT` kind of hide that from you?

Comment: You could use a Dictionary object to store your DNS pairs. You don't have to worry about resizing.

Comment: Useful: [Comparison of Dictionary, Collections and Arrays](//stackoverflow.com/a/32479872) and [Erase vs ReDim In Arrays](//stackoverflow.com/a/38129242)

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville would agree that `Scripting.Dictionary` would be the better choice as long as it doesn't get too big.

Comment: I commented the "On error resume next" eventually, thanks for the answer to my "dumb question"

Comment: It would have worked for me to use a dictionary object, probably... But the existing code I was adapting was using the subscripted variable to perform file moves, so I eventually found that I could ReDim Preserve an array variable and got it working that way... I'll post the updated code for future Stack Overflow use (and because I couldn't find the answer elsewhere)

Comment: Update has been posted.. thanks to all for the brainstorming.  The updates are after "EDIT" .. so teh original postings will make sense